# ldapsearch Or other means to verify users

Tags: centos, ldap

I tried a few answers on ldapsearch usage and yet couldn't authenticate with the ldap service from a linux server. I am not sure what parameters to use?
I am trying this command

```
ldp=ldap://ldap.xyz.com
user=joe.john 
ldapsearch -x -D "uid=$user,dc=xyz,dc=com" \
           -W -H $ldp -b "dc=xyz,dc=com" \
           -s sub 'uid=$user'

Error :
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: Unable to bind to the Directory Server as user uid=joe.john,dc=xyz,dc=com because no such user exists in the server
```

I am not sure of the above parameters , though I tried various options
I am not sure who to ask in the current organization.
Once I authenticate myself, I also need to verify a few other user ids
using same command or other means.

Answer (score 0):

The `ldapsearch` syntax looks good, so it should work.

The first thing (however trivial) is to check if you use the correct password.

If you absolutely sure you gave the correct password, then you maybe specified your user incorrectly. When binding to LDAP, you need to give the exact DN of your user. You gave `uid=$user,dc=xyz,dc=com`, which is odd-looking to me (though syntactically correct), since users usually reside somewhere "deeper", in their own `ou`. So if your user's DN is actually `uid=$user,ou=users,ou=auth,dc=xyz,dc=com`, then you can't bind with the one you used.

If the DN is correct, you might want to try adding the `-Z` option (which issues StartTLS), or using `ldaps` instead of `ldap`. Perhaps the LDAP directory is configured to reject any authentications attempted on a non-encrypted connection.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I have no idea what is DN actually. Is there any command to get this info? OR, is there any file's (such as under etc or such) content I should look for to know how to make a query? Etc

Comment: DN stand for "Distinguished Name", and it is (in the case of LDAP) something like `uid=user,ou=unit,dc=domain,dc=com`. There is no way to guess this if you don't know the structure of the LDAP database. You should ask the administrators of the LDAP server for more info.